# Connected ScatterPlot with sapUI5 VizFrame

Tags: sapui5, scatter-plot

In my UI5 app I need to implement a "connected scatterplot" like this one:
[image: zFrame]

I can't find a way to do something similar using the [Scatter Plot](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.viz.ui5.controls.VizFrame/sample/sap.viz.sample.Scatter) of the VizFrame library.

Since I usually prefer to stick to the standard, I looked into the [CVOM Visualization](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.60.1/docs/vizdocs/index.html#reference/chartProperty/Charts/Scatter%20%20(5)/Scatter%20Plot/) properties if there is some property I could leverage but I can't find a suitable one. 
Am I missing something or should I use d3.js in a custom control as stated in [this](https://blogs.sap.com/2019/03/28/creating-custom-ui5-control-from-d3-chart/) blog post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully ended up in embedding a d3.js connected scatterplot into a custom component